# crystal report it is running perfectly on Windaws 7 and 8 but when i am running it on windows xp it is asking userid and password

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have one crystal report it is running perfectly on Windaws 7 and 8 but when i am running it on windows xp it is asking userid and password. And all other reports are working fine i have verifyed this report from anohter system.

Comment: This "Logon" screen will usually pop-up if a connection cannot be made to the data source, for whatever reason. You said other reports work on this computer, so it can talk to the server and you said this report works on other computers. The only thing I can think of is the provider used on the report. For example, the 2 most popular for SQL Server is the OLEDB provider and the SQLCLI10?? provider. They work very differently and the SQLCLI might not even be supported on XP? Make sure this report uses the same provider as the ones that do work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by declaring this in your code.

For example `report.SetDatabaseLogon(user, pwd)`

You can also write it to the registry but to put it in your code is better.

Comment: Thanks for your time but still problem is coming. this report is working fine on windows 7 and windows 8 with same SQl connection, problem is coming only on windows xp